# Cannot @Autowire configuration

Tags: java, selenium, testng, spring-framework-beans

I am absolutely new to TestNG, Spring framework etc. and I'm trying to use the annotation `@Value` access to configuration file via the `@Configuration` annotation.

All I'm trying to achieve here is to make the console write out "hi" from the config file accessing the value via `@Value`. I must be obviously missing the whole point of the `@Value` annotation (or `@Autowired` or some other annotations) as all I'm gettting is `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

I have the following three files (reduced to the absolute minimum):

config.properties

```
a="hi"
```

TestConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("config.properties")
public class TestConfiguration {
    @Value("${a}")
    public String A;
}
```

TrialTest.java

```
public class TrialTest {
    @Autowired
    private TestConfiguration testConfiguration;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(testConfiguration.A);
   }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can look into this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779838/cannot-autowired-beans-when-separate-configuration-classes

Comment: You aren't using the Spring runner, so your test class isn't inspected for injection. See the Spring Test docs for how to do this with TestNG.

Comment: A `@Configiration` is not intended to be `@Autowired`, it is intended for creating and configuring beans.

Comment: @yinon It's perfectly acceptable to autowire it, though. It's a bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try annotate your test class with these:

<del>@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)</del>

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={TestConfiguration.class})
```

[Edit] sorry I didn't see that OP was using TestNG. The essential point is still that the problem is caused by Spring not being bootstrapped. In TestNG that can be done via extending `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`.

Comment: OP specifically said TestNG.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm afraid I'll be soon back with more questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your config, you are declaring the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean which can resolve the @Value expressions. Declare this bean:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("config.properties")
public class TestConfiguration {
    @Value("${a}")
    public String A;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()
    {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Note that you do not have to do anything with this bean, just by declaring it, it will allow the @Value annotation expressions to work as expected.

You can either redundantly declare this bean in every class that uses a @Value annotation, but that would be bad practice/style as it would keep overwriting the bean in each new declaration. Instead, place this bean at the top most config which imports other configs using @Value and you can recycle the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean from the one place.